# Regex to match three quote string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have this string( like python doc ):

```
"""
1 string with two lines
in this area
"""
"""
2 string, but with more "quotes"
"""
"""
3 string
multiline and "multiquote"
"""
```

I need:

```
array(
[0] => 1 string with two lines
    in this area

[1] => 2 string, but with more "quotes"
[2] => 3 string
    multiline and "multiquote"

)
```

But, i have:

```
/(?<!""")(?<=(?!""").)"(?!""")/im
```

And:

```
/(\x22\x22\x22)[\w\s\d\D\W\S.]+(?\x22\x22\x22)/i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this https://eval.in/126887

```
preg_match_all("/\"{3}(.*?)\"{3}/s", $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

why dont you code it like this

```
$re = '/"""(.*?)"""/is'; 
$str = '"""
1 string with two lines
in this area
"""
"""
2 string, but with more "quotes"
"""
"""
3 string
multiline and "multiquote"
"""'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[1]);

output:

Array
(
    [0] => 
1 string with two lines
in this area

    [1] => 
2 string, but with more "quotes"

    [2] => 
3 string
multiline and "multiquote"

)
```